# Netlab - How are the errors calculated?

Tags: matlab, validation, neural-network, gradient-descent, mean-square-error

I'm trying to optimise and validate a neural network using Netlab on Matlab

I'd like to find the error value for each iteration, so I can see convergence on a plot. This can be done by storing the errors presented in the command window which is done by setting **options(1)** to **1** using **errlog** is a **netopt** output.

However these errors are not the same as **mlperr** which gives an error value of **0.5*(sum of squares error)** for the last iteration. I can't really validly use them if I don't know how they're calculated.

Does anybody know what the errors displayed in the command window represent (I'm using **scaled conjugate gradient** as my optimisation algorithm)?

Is there a way of storing the **mlperr** for each iteration that the network 
runs?

Any help is greatly appreciated, many thanks!

**NB:**
I have tried doing something similar to this : 
ftp://ftp.dcs.shef.ac.uk/home/spc/com336/neural-lab-wk6.html

However it gives different results to running the network with the number of iterations specified under options(14) rather than k for some reason.

Comment: You may need to post a code sample to get more directed help. What did you try? In short please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have managed to fix the issue! The errors given in as an errorlog through netopt are indeed the same as those given in mlperr, however one was calculated using my validation set, and one from my training set, which have significant numbers of data points, which explains the difference!

Comment: If you don't mind, perhaphs it will be nice to post the solution to your question as an answer, this may help someone out in the future :) +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes certainly,

The *ERRLOG* vector, created as an output to the network optimisation function *netopt* with the following syntax

```
[NET, OPTIONS, ERRLOG] = netopt(NET, OPTIONS, X, T, ALG)
```

Each row of *ERRLOG* gives 0.5*SSE (sum of squares error) for the corresponding iteration of network optimisation. This error is calculated between the predicted outputs (y) and the target outputs (t).

The *MLPERR* function, hast the following syntax

```
E = mlperr(NET, X, T)
```

It also gives 0.5*SSE between predicted outputs (y) and target outputs (t), but as the network parameters are constant (NET should be pre-trained), *E* is a singular value.

If *netopt* was run with an *ERRLOG* output, and then *MLPERR* was run with the same network and variables, *E* should be the same value as value of the final row  of *ERRLOG* (the error after the final iteration of network optimisation).

Hope this is of some use to someone!